# Generate Hexcode in php

Tags: c#, php, javascript, asp-classic

basically i want to create a pin in digit only and token in HEXADECIMAL form and exact same length of 32bit and pin length is 5bit.

like a pin code i have

> PIN: 15458 and its token code is  Toke:
>   93f23ed246e7b2c47b5dbc6a341f2354
>
> PIN: 60703  and its token code is Token:
>   43e0e636d3f6b17615c96e2b5a9a908a

i want something like this programatically in php, asp, c#, javascript whatever is suitable to generate easily.

In which i can use in series like  FOR LOOP statement

```
for($a = 10000; $a<60000; $a++)
{
   echo  $a." = ".  token algorithm exactly like mentioned aboved.
}
```

suppose the for loop statement reaches $a = 15458

then it generate a token 93f23ed246e7b2c47b5dbc6a341f2354

token algorithm is the actual thing which i want.

Comment: I don't really see a question here, but you are looking for a hash algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32bit hex code is basically going to be only 4 characters long - you mean a 32 character code?

The simplest (and these days least reliable) method is to simply use `md5()`:

```
$token = md5('60703'); // d0e98b043981d95898b7aa85f8e4978f
```

Comment: While `md5()` may not be used for security related issues anymore, there should be no problem using it as a simple (and fast) way to generate a hexadecimal token (using it for non-security related issues, etc..)?

Comment: it is possible to generate a same token for `15458` and its token is `93f23ed246e7b2c47b5dbc6a341f2354` or another pin is `60703` and token is `43e0e636d3f6b17615c96e2b5a9a908a`

Comment: nope. it's fine for that. but if it's being used in a context where you can't have collisions, then md5 is a bad choice - it's trivial to compute a collision in md5 these days.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed: md5() is a constant tranform. the md5 of a value today is going to be the same md5 tomorrow. As for generating your EXACT token codes, no idea. We're not cryptographers, and we're not going to waste our day trying to figure out the algorithm used to build those tokens.